# C++ Difference between class attributes and object attributes

Tags: c++

**Questions :**
What is the difference between : `time.m_seconds = m_seconds + b.m_seconds;` and `time.m_seconds = time.m_seconds + b.m_seconds;` and `time.m_seconds = this->m_seconds + b.m_seconds;` ? They dont give the same output.

**The problem :**
Expected output : 20:35:36 /
Actual output : 20:34:36 /
Output with `time.m_seconds = time.m_seconds + b.m_seconds;` : 20:34:44

**The code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Time {
    private:
        int m_hours;
        int m_minutes;
        int m_seconds;

    public:
        Time(int hours = 0, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0) : m_hours(hours), m_minutes(minutes), m_seconds(seconds) { };

        void print() {
            cout << m_hours << ":" << m_minutes << ":" << m_seconds;
        }

        Time operator+(const Time& b) {
            Time time;
            //1 : ajout des secondes
            time.m_seconds = m_seconds + b.m_seconds;
            //Si le nombre de secondes dépasse 60, on rajoute des minutes
            //Et on met un nombre de secondes inférieur à 60
            time.m_minutes = m_minutes + (m_seconds / 60);
            time.m_seconds %= 60;

            //2 : ajout des minutes
            time.m_minutes = m_minutes + b.m_minutes;
            //Si le nombre de minutes dépasse 60, on rajoute des heures
            //Et on met un nombre de minutes inférieur à 60
            time.m_hours = m_hours + (m_minutes / 60);
            time.m_minutes %= 60;

            //3 : ajout des heures
            time.m_hours = m_hours + b.m_hours;
            return time;
        }

};

int main() {
    Time time1(12, 25, 52);
    Time time2(8, 9, 44);
    Time result(0,0,0);

    result = time1 + time2;
    result.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m_seconds` refers to the `m_seconds` from the left hand side of the `+` and is the same as `this->m_seconds`. `time.m_seconds` refers to the `m_seconds` of the function's local variable `time`, which immediately after being default-constructed is `0`. Also note that `time.m_minutes = m_minutes + b.m_minutes` completely overwrites the value calculated in `time.m_minutes = m_minutes + (m_seconds / 60)`.

Comment: Ok thanks I will update an answer so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the explanation of @Nathan Pierson this is the answer to my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Time {
    private:
        int m_hours;
        int m_minutes;
        int m_seconds;

    public:
        Time(int hours = 0, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0) : m_hours(hours), m_minutes(minutes), m_seconds(seconds) { };

        void print() {
            cout << m_hours << ":" << m_minutes << ":" << m_seconds;
        }

        Time operator+(const Time& b) {
            Time time;
            time.m_seconds = m_seconds + b.m_seconds; // time.m_seconds = 96
            time.m_minutes = m_minutes + (time.m_seconds / 60); // time.m_minutes = 25 + 1 = 26
            time.m_seconds %= 60; // time.m_seconds = 36

            time.m_minutes = time.m_minutes + b.m_minutes; // time.m_minutes = 26 + 9 = 35
            time.m_hours = m_hours + (time.m_minutes / 60); // time.m_hours = 12 + 0
            time.m_minutes %= 60; // time.m_minutes = 35

            time.m_hours = time.m_hours + b.m_hours; // time.m_hours = 12 + 8 = 20
            return time;
        }

};

int main() {
    Time time1(12, 25, 52);
    Time time2(8, 9, 44);
    Time result(0,0,0);

    result = time1 + time2;
    result.print();

    return 0;
}
```